# Deploy/host multiple angular 2 apps on same gcp bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've 2 angular projects 1st ng-admin and 2nd ng-supplier. I want to deploy both projects in same gcp bucket. What should I do I don't want multiple index.html for both projects.
Eg
admin-9880 (bucket on gcp)
-index.html (files from dist folder after hitting ng build command)
-main.js

Deploy multiple angular projects in same gcp bucket

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you want with Cloud Storage and Google Cloud.

It's better to use different bucket (for rolling out, management and so on). In addition, you can't route the traffic based on the port, but only on the domain name and/or the path.

If you choose path, you can use only one bucket, and put your source in the correct path in Cloud Storage (for instance /admin for the admin angular app, and you will access it with the HTTP path : domain.com/admin)

If you choose domain name, you can have admin.domain.com and domain.com that redirect to the different backend.

---

By writing this answer, I'm thinking to something I never tested: you could use a mono bucket and put the angular app in their respective Cloud Storage path (as before, /admin for the admin app).

But you can try to use the [URL Rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite) to change the input path to match it to your bucket structure. Like that, you don't have a strict relationship between your GCS structure and your HTTP path logic.